# How do I fix the error given from "drush en nodejs -y"?

Tags: drush

When I run `drush en nodejs -y`, I get this error.

> In PmCommands.php line 247: Unable to install modules nodejs due to missing modules nodejs.

How do I fix that error?

I am using Drush 10.2.2 and Composer 1.10.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`drush en` doesn't download the modules anymore. That must be done with Composer.

```
composer require drupal/nodejs
drush en nodejs -y
```

If `composer require drupal/nodejs` was executed, the module could have been saved in the wrong directory, for example in the vendor directory.

In that case, I would check the *composer.json* file to verify it doesn't instruct Composer to install the modules in the wrong directory. In *composer.json* there should be a line similar to the following one, under *installer-paths*.

```
"modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"]
```

If the *composer.json file contains lines similar to the following lines, check that *web-root* is using the correct web root directory. (Some servers could use *public_html* instead of *web*.)

```
"drupal-scaffold": {
    "locations": {
        "web-root": "web/"
    }
}
```